# django contains model with ManyToMany fields, but they are not available with query

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model that contains two ManyToMany fields, and I have successfully created entries containing these fields. When I create a queryset, the data from here isn't included. How can I access that data?

Queryset code:

```
example_list = Example.objects.values_list().order_by('-date_submitted')
```

Models.py

```
class Example(models.Model):
    example_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_submitted = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField()
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='design_photos')
    materials = models.ManyToManyField('Materials')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tags')
```

Comment: Do you mean the data representing the relationships isn't there, or the related data from the foreign objects isn't there? E.g. is it showing you materials = material1, material2, or is it just ignoring those two fields altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by use of the filter method, as follows:

```
example_list = Example.objects.filter(tags__tag__contains='jewellery').order_by('-date_submitted')[:10]
```